# Mailchimp form in Bootstrap - Button moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I included a Mailchimp form into my responsive bootstrap page, but the structure does not seem right for my design.

When I click on the button to the right, the js error response and the success response got an impact on the button and moves the button down a bit.

You can see what I mean here: http://jsbin.com/garefamati/edit?html,css,output

I want the button to stay in place, even if got a message from the error or success handler.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the style `vertical-align: top;` to the button wrapper element `<span class="input-group-btn">`.

This will override the vertical alignment style rule for `.input-group-addon, .input-group-btn` that is causing the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: yeah thats it. Thank you